# using the Unix alias command in C program

Tags: c, unix, alias

So I'm not exactly sure if this is possible, but I would like to use unix's alias command for creating aliases of commands I have created inside of my C program.

So far the only idea I have had to try is system(alias ='someCommand');
This resulted in nothing happening

Is this even possible? Or do I have to essentially create my own alias function for my c program (which is a simple shell program)

Thanks, I'm new to this and would appreciate any insight!

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd want to do this. Aliases are for humans, so we don't have to type as much. Your C++ program really doesn't care about that.

Comment: `system()` will invoke a shell, create an alias in it, then the shell exits and the alias is destroyed... You need to create the aliases OUTSIDE of your program, before it executes

Comment: What do you mean by "commands created inside of my C program"? Do you mean functions you've written?

Comment: `Is this even possible?` -- __NO__

Comment: I'm writing a shell program. An example of a command in my program would be if the user enters history as a command, the program will display the last 10 commands entered. I'm required to have a alias functionality, I'm just struggling with figuring out a solution to achieve this.

Comment: Will alias even work on variables inside a C program, or do I need to create a linked-list (an idea I have) for each command to emulate the alias functionality

Answer (score 1):

Aliases are meant as shortcuts that you create to reduce your typing when working inside the shell.  When you execute a program that you created by compiling your C source code, the shell `fork`s and `exec`s the program.  Any changes that you intend to make to the shell happen inside that `exec`ed code.  As soon as the program is terminated, your changes disappear with it.  Hence, what you observe: "Nothing happens".